# jQuery UI Accordion Scrolling issue

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a page with several sections of significantly varying length within a jQuery UI Accordion.  If I open a new section (which collapses one of the longer sections above), I'm left at the bottom of the page.  Because the sections are of significantly different heights, I can't use the autoheight feature without it looking very strange.  Is there any way to use something like scrollto to automatically go to the top of the section I've just expanded?

Answer (score 2):

You can bind a function to the `accordionchange` event and use jQuery `scrollTop()`:

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        header: "h3"
    });

    $('#accordion').bind('accordionchange', function (event, ui) {
        $(window).scrollTop(ui.newHeader.offset().top);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">
    <div id="accordion-one">
        <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
        <div>Some lengthy text</div>
    </div>
    <div id="accordion-two">
        <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3>
        <div>Less lengthy text</div>
    </div>
    <div id="accordion-three">
        <h3><a href="#">Third</a></h3>
        <div>Other text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tested this in FF8.

**Links**

- [Accordion change event](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#event-change)
- [jQuery `scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)